# Using Amazon Route 53 Elastic IP vs Delegation Set in Godaddy

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I started Amazon EC2 instance, installed rails environment and succeeded running my rails app.

I wanted to direct a **subdomain** to that instance. My domain registrar is Godaddy. So, sub.example.com should point to my instance.

So, (1) I attached an elastic IP to my Amazon instance. (2) Added an A record to the Amazon Route 53 Hosted zone for my domain, connecting Elastic IP and the subdoman. For the next step I tryed to enter domain server records from delegation set of Route 53 to Godaddy Zone file. But I couldn't manage to do that. Then I just added A record and pointed sub.example.com to the Elastic IP.

My question, is there a way to use those delegation sets in Godaddy? Or maybe there are for something else?

Also, I found this http://support.godaddy.com/groups/domains-management-and-services/forum/topic/delegated-subdomain/ Maybe it is impossible to use NS records for subdomains. By the way, sub.example.com is redirecting to Amazon instance, what I did in Godaddy console works.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GoDaddy doesn't allow subdomains to have NS records, but this isn't a technological restriction of any sort. It's just GoDaddy not allowing it.

Your best bet is likely ditching GoDaddy entirely for the DNS component and let Route53 serve both your main domain and your subdomain DNS records.